# zendform not loading

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i am using zend framework, i use auto loader to load the class, i create a Zend_Form in this page http://tedxnanjing.com/displayevent/TEDxNanjing%2Bcoming%2Bsoon%2B11%252F27
but the form is not loading, this page works fine in my own local environment , except i am using php 5.3 , but i check that it should work with php 5.2.4 and later.
why this happening?

this is a test page with more detail http://zend.anpingsiwang.info/events/TEDxNanjing%2Bcoming%2Bsoon%2B11%252F27

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the link. Can you be a little more specific on what you need help with?

Comment: there should be a comment form at the bottom of the page which is not, i know it is tricky to show the problem, let me know what else you need.

Comment: There is no exception thrown by Zend. The form does not appear in your view, correct?

Comment: no , no error, no exception. i tried this code :try{
   $form = new Tedxnanjing_Form_usrcomment();
   $this->view->form = $form;
  }catch(Exception $e){
   $this->view->message=$e->getTraceAsString();
  } nothing comes out.

Comment: Typically you could enable errors and throw exceptions in your production environment (just to get you over this hump), and/or check PHP error logs for the host, and/or setup exception logging in your app and review those logs.

Comment: How do you call/output the form within your view? Don't forget to render the form by it's `render`-method.

Comment: Can you provide the form code? And the code in your view script?

Answer (score 0):

found the bug. it is the `addFilter('HTMLEntities')` that keeps the form not being rendered.
haven't found why this happening , may something with my environment or a zend bug, just point it out first.